# Windows Is Plugged In and not charging after disassembling laptop

Tags: windows, laptop, motherboard, battery, connector

I disassembled a laptop (an ASUS ROG G752VY) to replace a CR2032 bios battery. It was disassembled for two days with the motherboard disconnected from the laptop battery.

When I re-assembled the laptop, the first time I realized I hadn't plugged the battery back into the motherboard since it was not detecting any battery at all. However, when I took it apart again, I noticed this and plugged it back in. Even though it's plugged back in now, I'm still having an issue:

[image]

[image]

When I am in Windows, it shows an "empty" battery symbol that says "Plugged in, not charging." I tested unplugging the laptop while it was turned on, and it immediately powered off. So clearly the battery isn't working.

I also noticed that the laptop has an LED for the battery that is flashing red constantly, even after being plugged in for hours.

Any idea what's causing this or how to fix it? Everything should be plugged back into the motherboard now, so I don't know if this was caused by me powering it on at one point without the battery connected or if it is something else. Did I damage the battery somehow?

Comment: Are you able to do a re-assembly?   Otherwise it would be sheer guesswork to know

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cnet.com/tech/computing/how-to-fix-a-windows-10-laptop-thats-plugged-in-but-isnt-charging/

I found one article that might be able to fix the problem.

**It says to;**

1. Go to device manager and find the batteries section.
2. Expand it and find 2 drivers there.
3. Select each and uninstall it.
4. Now Shutdown your Laptop, and then unplug the charger cable.
5. Also remove your battery, if its removable. or else you will have to remove the back cover and remove the battery and reconnect it.
6. After reconnecting everything, turn on your laptop.

The problem should be solved now. Try it and keep me posted.